# Javascript values in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I calculated some values in JavaScript, now I want to print them in the name *HTML* page.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow :). Can you show us your code, please?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics learn some basics and try once

Comment: we can't see your screen :)  please post your code

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourValue = "hello";
document.getElementById("name").value = yourValue;
```